# Emacs -*- lang -* tag and old-style K&R C

Tags: c, emacs

I'm working on a big project, which uses many programming languages, and I have absolutely no experience with Emacs. I searched on Google on information about how `-*- this -*-` works, but didn't find anything.

For example, if I have a file `test.krc`, meaning to be in old-style K&R C, how should I mark this on it for Emacs to recognize?

If anyone could explain how the `-*- lang -*-` tag works, I would appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Specifying File Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html).

```
# -*- text -*-
```

is just a shorthand for

```
# -*- mode: text -*-
```

*Summarising the important bits from the comments below:*
In this case, the following comment on the first line will have the desired effect:

```
/* -*- mode: c; c-file-style: "k&r"; -*- */
```

Comment: Is this case-sensitive? And how could I set the mode for K&R C? Can this be in any part of a comment? I mean, could I use `* Language: Blablabla (-*- blablabla -*-). *`? Is it possible to define the version of the language (like C99 and C11)?

Comment: Paulo Torrens: I think you probably want to use `-*- mode: c; c-default-style "k&r"; -*-` (based on http://emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC )

Comment: Make them into comments so the compiler doesn't trip over them. And to get a reasonable indenting style, use the Linux' default configuration for emacs from its [CodingStyle](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/CodingStyle), search for emacs. That way you don't need the `c-default-style` (and get a much nicer one to boot). And BTW, K&R C isn't different enough to current C to need another indentation style.

Comment: vonbrand: surely that would have to be "current C isn't different enough to K&R C to need another indentation style"? (I'm not sure exactly what "current C" means, but it's fairly clear which came first :)

Comment: But it needs different keyword lists, for example. Aparently, Emacs doesn't make this distinction, so I guess (thanks to phils) `-*- mode: c; c-default-style "k&r"; -*-` will work. The link plus a bit of testing myself taught everything I needed. Thanks you all. :)

Comment: One last thing: If *all* C files in the project directory need K&R style, you can use a single `.dir-locals.el` file to set `c-default-style` for all `c-mode` files in that directory tree. See `C-h i g (emacs) Directory Variables RET`

Comment: Oh, and it looks as if you actually want to set the variable `c-file-style` rather than `c-default-style` when doing this with a file local variable.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative, if the files in question actually do have a `.krc` extension:

```el
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.krc\\'" . c-mode))
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-hook)
(defun my-c-mode-hook ()
  (when (and buffer-file-name
             (equal (file-name-extension buffer-file-name) "krc"))
    (c-set-style "k&r")))
```

Comment: Is there a way to define that *inside* the *.krc file? Otherwise I would rather put `-*- mode: c; c-default-style "k&r"; -*-` on the file.

Comment: No, this is a way of configuring the behaviour *without* using file local variables. If your preference is to use the file local variable comments, then you can ignore this answer entirely.